# Missing required modules: ‘B'

Tags: swift, import, frameworks

The swift dynamic library Framework A introduces the static library Framework B, and B is linked into A. But when A is introduced in the Swift demo, an error is reported: Missing required modules: "B".

I want to avoid the error: Missing required modules: 'B'. What should i do?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.